# Problem when calling .net webservice?

Tags: .net, android, web-services

i created a sample android app i.e. calling simple .net webservice and displaying in TextView, below are the code prospects:

web service code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string MobileApp(string acNum) 
    {
        return "Account number is"+acNum;
    }

}
```

android app code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;


public class AccountDetails extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/MobileApp";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "MobileApp";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:58817/MobService/Service.asmx";
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.accountdet);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tView);
ServiceCall();
    }
    public void ServiceCall()
    {
        try{
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        request.addProperty("acNum", "123456");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        tv.setText(result.toString());

        }       
        catch (final IOException e)

        {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (final XmlPullParserException e)

        {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (final Exception e)

        {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
```

Also i added below lines to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

But i didn't get the result in TextView, so any one plz help me.

@nagaraju.

Comment: Do you know whether your web service receives the call?

Comment: localhost is android-emulator not your PC

Comment: @shlublu how can i check it ?

Comment: @selvin Then is there any changes i've to do?

Comment: just change localhost to 10.0.2.2 or to your.computer.local.ip

Comment: @selvin yeah! i changed it to 10.0.2.2 but didn't get response, also tried with my local IP.

Comment: 1. show as your stack trace ... 2. what you see if you put http://localhost:58817/MobService/Service.asmx to your browser on PC ? 3. do you have internet conention in emu ?

Comment: @selvin 1. i'm new to this apps so don't know how to do it?  2. It displays web method in browser  3. yeah! i've internet connection on my emu.

Comment: maybe WebDev.WebServer not accepting connections from outside ... install IIS and put webservice there

Comment: @Selvin inspect the log files of your webservice or set a breakpoint ini it while trying a call, to see how it behaves exactly.

Comment: @Shlublu :) i'm not OP ... i don't remeber but i think that i got same problem coz WebDev server not accepting connection outside ... so i installed IIS and i'm using IIS instead of builtin Visual Studio web server

Comment: @selvin Ok 'm adding it to IIS now, before that can you tell me is there any corrections in my code? or it looking perfect.

Comment: i'm not familiar with ksoap instead of e.printStackTrace(); use Log.e("myprog", e.toString()) and provide Log from Logcat (<= google for logcat window in Eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my bug, it is simple, As i put user permission lines in manifest file in the application tag but actually, I've to put outside of the application tag so that's why i'm getting the response.

Thanks one n all for replying me, your replies also help me to learn stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

First check whether your service is running-- for that try in the browser with your link,[link](http://localhost:58817/MobService/Service.asmx),then create dummy site , in there call your method `MobileApp`, If its return then your service is working prefect.

```
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopes = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap//// envelope
    envelopes.dotNet = true;
    envelopes.setOutputSoapObject(requestData);
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(APPURL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelopes);
        responsesData = (SoapPrimitive) envelopes.getResponse();

    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try This one..

Comment: Hi Nagkeeran, Thanx for your reply currently i'm using HttpTransportSE class for transmitting the msg is this correct one? if i use AndroidHttpTransport class it showing warning like "The type AndroidHttpTransport is deprecated", Still i didn't getting the result after changing code as you said that :(

Comment: your tesing/ dummy site return (service) any result? did you try?

Comment: Actually i'm running my service in other local system from there i'm using that service, but if i paste that local system address in my browser it doesn't displaying the service. So is there any changes i've to when i'm using service from local system 'm giving link like "http://192.158.0.34:54888/MobService/Service.asmx"

Comment: So Problem in your service.. If the service running, that mean showing xml format result in your browser then only you can make sure your service is working

Comment: ya that's ok. But even i'm running service in my system not other one service is running fine and when 'm clicking invoke button it showing me XML format but didn't getting response. The link which 'm using in my system is like "http://192.188.0.77:52289/MobService/Service.asmx" this link is using in my code.

Comment: I cant see this service. In your case Service running different machine & running code is different machine. So You should check that service is ruuning in your machine

Comment: My above example is running both service and code in same machine, but just now i checked in by deploying service in other machine but its not working. Can you tell me the correct way to call service from other machine?

Comment: ya done, i putted service in other machine IIS server and calling from my local browser now its working fine 'm getting the service from remote machine. So i'm using link from the remote machine to access service but still didn't getting the result? :(

Comment: oops i'm getting soap messages right? so how can i extract the result and display in my machine emu?

Comment: yap. What is you method return type? is it Primitive or JSON? if its String String result = responseData.toString();

Comment: so i'm getting soap messages, from above code is correct for getting result from soap messages or any changes. ya 'm reading like: SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        TextView txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tView);
          txtView.setText(result.toString());

Comment: Then try like this String String result = responseData.toString(); did you get the response correctly

Comment: so i'm getting soap messages, from above code is correct for getting result from soap messages or any changes. ya 'm reading like: SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); TextView txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tView); txtView.setText(result.toString()); But didn't getting the response.

Comment: above this line print System.out.println(result.toString) then String s = result.toStringtxtView.setText(s); If it is ok accept the answer

Comment: And i'm giving soap aciton and namespace like "http://tempuri.org/MobileApp" and ""http://tempuri.org/"

Comment: ya i tried as you said that but not getting anything? i don't know what the problem is but everything looks fine and correct. If you don't mine can i give my project link to you and check it?

Comment: Hey have you finished it? if you don't finish send me